# python datetime, is this syntax correct?

Tags: python, datetime

I was writing code to modify the modify the year in a `datetime` object, and I accidentally did the wrong thing, and it initially worked. Here is the cut-down code:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0)
d2 = datetime.datetime.replace(d, 2001)
d3 = d.replace(year=2001)
match = d2 == d3
print("d2 = %s, d3 = %s, match = %s" % (d2, d3, match))
```

Output:

```
d2 = 2001-01-01 12:00:00, d3 = 2001-01-01 12:00:00, match = True
```

The code to create d3 is correct according to the python `datetime` documentation (because `datetime.datetime.replace` is a method). But somehow the code to create `d2` also worked, even though I cannot find any documentation saying `datetime.datetime.replace` can be used as a function. I am using Python 3.8.10

So my question is: is my code to create `d2` correct, or did I just "get lucky", perhaps due to a quirk in the implementation?

The reason I ask is that, when I use the `d2` code, I get a really nasty segmentation fault later on. So either the `d2` code is wrong (in which case Python should have raised an exception), or it is right (in which case I should submit a bug report for the package which core dumps).

Comment: That's the way Python works - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21366809/1270789).

Comment: Fair enough. That makes my segmentation core example even stranger. I'll probably post that soon.